# django and url creation

Tags: django, url-pattern

I want to construct the following url

```
domain/edit/xray/<id>/<image_name>
```

where id is a model's id and image_name is the name of an image.

I have an app that will handle image editing with its own views lets say it mypil

mypil.views

```
def edit_xray(request, id, image_name):
    ....code to get image by name
    ....model by id and edit image using PIL
        model = Model.objects.get(pk=id)
```

project/urls.py

```
url(r'^edit/', include(mypil.urls))
```

mypil.urls

```
url(r'^xray/(?P<id>)\d+/(?P<image_name>)\w+\.\w{3}$', mypil.views.edit_xray)
```

But when i try to view edit/xray/1/image.jpg (both id and image exist) i encounter this problem.

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

and the traceback shows me that line above

```
model=Model.objects.get(pk=id)
```

Does the empty string('') mean that it doesn't parse the id correctly from the URL? Isn't my url pattern correct?

EDIT: Damn my eyes....needed to put \d+ and the image reg pattern inside the parentheses

```
url(r'^xray/(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<image_name>\w+\.\w{3})$,...)
```

Sorry for posting a question...(How do i delete my own questions?)

Comment: Don't delete it, it's not a bad question. Someone might do the same mistake again

Comment: Is it really? Just not being cautious enough lol :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct url is:

```
url(r'^xray/(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<image_name\w+\.\w{3})$', mypil.views.edit_xray)
```

You should put the pattern in the parentnesses.

Comment: Keeping the trailing slash is a good practice, in my opinion.